# How to represent datetime of different time zones in C#

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have a .NET WebService (written in C#), that is supposed to serve people around the world.
With each request I get the user's datetime in his own time zone with the format : `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm ZZZZ`.
I have to convert the string to something representing the **original** date and time and specifying the time zone in GMT. I have to make some logical calculations and keep it in the database.

The regular DateTime doe's not support this. it does not have a property specifying the time zone. When I try to convert my string into DateTime -  it simply converts it to my local time.

I do **not** want to keep my time in UTC, because I have some logic that has to run per user by his own time.

Does anyone know a C# class that handles this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can parse it with DateTimeOffset.  For example:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var s = "2009/01/10 17:18:44 -0800";
        var dto = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(s, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss zzzz", null);
        var utc = dto.UtcDateTime;
        Console.WriteLine(utc);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output: 1/11/2009 1:18:44 AM

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear whether ZZZZ means just an offset (which isn't complete time zone information) or the name of a time zone. It matters because the offset will change over time, usually due to daylight saving time.

If it's just an offset, then `DateTimeOffset` from .NET 2.0SP1 will cover everything you need (but you'll have to be careful due to having incomplete information).

If it's a real time zone name, `TimeZoneInfo` from .NET 3.5 *may* help you - depending on the format of the name. That uses Windows names (e.g. "GMT standard time") instead of the more common zoneinfo names (e.g. "Europe/London"). You'll need to store a `DateTime` or (preferrably) `DateTimeOffset` along with the `TimeZoneInfo`.

In the future, [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) should be able to do this for you more easily - but it's not ready for prroduction yet.

Comment: I'm sorry, but i have to ask some more.if I get "2009/01/10 17:18:44 -0800" how do I parse it to get the timezone info and the date separately? do I have to cut the string and parse it by myself or are there built in methods that handle this?

Comment: @Mohoch: Hans has given you parsing code, but you need to be aware that that is *not* full time zone information. It's just the correct offset at that point in time. The same time zone is likely to have a different offset at a different time of year.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I am not interested in the location's timezone offset, just in the user's current offset. But I will keep this in mind if the scope changes.
Thank you very much.